# C# - SendInput() - Hold Key Down?

Tags: c#, keyboard, keydown, sendinput

**Current Functionality**
In a Direct3D environment, the key is held down. In a non Direct3D environment, it is simply pressed once.

```
    public static void HoldKey()
    {
        //Type = 1 means keyboard input.
        INPUT IP = new INPUT { Type = 1 };
        IP.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT();
        IP.Data.Keyboard.VirtualCode = 0;  //Zero for ignore virtual code.
        IP.Data.Keyboard.ScanCode = 0x39; // Spacebar scancode.
        IP.Data.Keyboard.Flags = 0x0008; //KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE
        IP.Data.Keyboard.Time = 0;
        IP.Data.Keyboard.ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

        INPUT[] Inputs = new INPUT[] { IP };
        //Key Press.
        SendInput(1, Inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
    }
```

It should be noted, that I am used the `ScanCode` field instead of the `VirtualCode` field because I do wish to send inputs to Direct3D applications.

**Desired Functionality**
I would like for the key to be held down, in both a Direct3D environment and a non Direct3D environment, akin to my holding down of the corresponding button on my physical keyboard.

**Additional Information**
I have seen some code using the `keybd_event()` function, although it does say on the MSDN website that it has been 'superseded'.

I have considered using the `SendMessage()` function instead to send a `WM_KEYDOWN` message, but I'm not sure if this would work.

Comment: How are you determining that the key is held down, particularly in the non-D3D environment?